# Not Reading in Last Input For Some Reason, but reads others

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

(Using java)

My old explanation of the problem is terrible so I'll re word it. Basically at the end of the code it should check if the user wants to rerun the program. Y == Repeat. N == End program. So why is this code not working? It is the same as what the other checks are doing but it almost seems like it skips those last two if statements. What is wrong?

```
      String loopy = in.nextLine();
      in.nextLine();
      if(loopy.equals("Y")){
        for(int count = 0;count<5;count++)
        {
          System.out.println("");
        }
      }
      if(loopy.equals("N"))
      {
        break; 
      }
    }
    System.out.println("You have chosen to exit the program. Program Finished");
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just swap the order of these two lines and your code will run well:

```
String loopy = in.nextLine();
in.nextLine();
```

Make it:

```
in.nextLine();
String loopy = in.nextLine();
```

Comment: Wow I feel so dumb. Thanks for the answer. It worked! I can't believe how simply the error was that i made.

Comment: Actually, it was previously reading an empty String (or a `\n` character) into `loopy` :)

Comment: You should put the lone `in.nextLine()` right after `double tendered = in.nextDouble()`; your error comes about because the trailing newline `\n` from entering your amount manually and pressing enter is still kept in `Scanner in`, only the numerical value is read.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're reading the answer to the last question twice:

```
   String loopy = in.nextLine();
   in.nextLine();
```

Comment: second `in.nextLine();` is used to discard the new line character `\n`

Comment: Well if I don't do that I get this:
`Do you want to take another order? (Y/N)Do you want a Burger? (Y/N)` (input box here for burger)

In one line.

Answer (score -1):

your while loop runs forever,

```
while(true)
```

loops forever, change true to check whether the answer to the last question is yes.

Comment: `break` statment is enough for breaking the loop

Comment: As @Eng.Fouad stated the break should break out of that loop thus I just used `while(true)`